# how to get last modified column name from mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to get a particular updated column name from a record?

if so, please help me. since i am creating a history table to store a updated column and their values from rest of the tables.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS testing.hisupdate;


CREATE TRIGGER testing.hisupdate AFTER
UPDATE ON testing.emp
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO testing.history (`id`,`revision_id`,`trx_code`, `trx_method`, `column_name`, `old_value`, `new_value`, `trx_timestamp`, `user_id`)
SELECT
  (SELECT emp_id
   FROM testing.emp
   ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT p.revision_id
   FROM testing.history AS p
   WHERE p.id=
       (SELECT emp_id
        FROM testing.emp
        ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT 1)
   ORDER BY trx_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) + 1, 'updt', 'update','null',
  (SELECT p.new_value
   FROM testing.history AS p
   WHERE p.id=
       (SELECT emp_id
        FROM testing.emp
        ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT 1)
   ORDER BY trx_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1), concat(p.emp_id,"/",p.emp_name,"/",p.salary,"/") AS new_value,
                                         NOW(),
                                         '101'
FROM testing.emp AS p
WHERE p.emp_id = new.emp_id;
```

i have created trigger but searching for a sub query for last updated column name.. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code...**

```
create table sales(orderno INT, sale INT,empsalary int, ts TIMESTAMP);

create table history(updated varchar(20), oldvalue INT,newvalue INT);

INSERT INTO sales (orderno,sale,empsalary) VALUES(1,700,7000);

INSERT INTO sales (orderno,sale,empsalary) VALUES(2,800,8000);

INSERT INTO sales (orderno,sale,empsalary) VALUES(3,900,9000);

DROP TRIGGER test.instrigger;
```

**DELIMITER ///**

```
CREATE TRIGGER test.instrigger AFTER UPDATE ON sales
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    IF NEW.sale <> OLD.sale THEN  
        INSERT INTO history (updated, oldvalue, newvalue) VALUES('sale', OLD.sale,NEW.sale);

    END IF;
    IF NEW.empsalary <> OLD.empsalary THEN  
        INSERT INTO history (updated, oldvalue, newvalue) VALUES('empsalary', OLD.empsalary,NEW.empsalary);
    END IF;
END;
```

///

**DELIMITER ;**

Comment: Once an `after` is executed, do you think, we still can access `OLD` ??